# Why doesn't a shape or form I've created fill in?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing, fill

Not new to Illustrator (actually studied this a few years ago).

I'm designing a logo by using a drawing tablet to trace over the design I drew with pencil.

When I go to fill the logo in, it doesn't fill in properly.

[image]

I know theres a simple explanation for why this is happening. I've made the shape form using paintbrush tool (I don't know if that's why perhaps).

Comment: One thing to try: Select all and fill the areas with the Shape Builder tool. It builds new closed areas using old borders. No guarantee it works if your paths are obscure enough. Double click the tool icon to be able to set gap detection ON. It's needed if your borders are not watertight. By holding Ctrl key you can combine adjacent areas and by holding Alt you can delete unwanted extras. Check the details from Illustrator User's guide.

Answer (score 1):

Your paths are not joined. There are breaks creating a collection of separate paths.

In order to fill things properly, paths need to be **connected** and the shapes they create need to be **closed shapes**.

[image]

You **can** use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to select two anchor points and then choose `Object > Path > Join` from the menu to connect disjointed paths.